# Errors after updating .NET Core MVC template's Nuget packages

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to build a .NET Core application. For this purpose I create a new MVC project from the template ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core).
Once I do this, I inevitably need to install some NuGet packages, and see that there are 26 updates available for my project. So I hit "update all" and get into a big mess. One was having to manually edit the project.json to make the .NETCore.App an object with {"version":"2.0.0","type":"platform"}. Now in the project.json most of the stuff is at version 2.0.0 but I get all these error messages in the Error List, and all of them say pretty much the same thing: **The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.0.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0**
What is my missing step?

Comment: Are you running in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Why yes, yes I am! One time I tried to use VS 2017 and it kept freezing so I uninstalled it and went back to 2015. Is that the problem?

Comment: VS2015 is no longer supported for .Net Core projects. You need to upgrade and migrate your `project.json` to `.csproj` too.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I hope they took care of the freezing issue. Do you want to make your comment an answer to be marked correct? Plus, I think it's extra confusing how they made the new packages available in VS2015 when they will just break everything.

Comment: The freezing issue is almost certainly your computer and not the fault of VS2017. Millions of other people are using it fine. As for the confusion you see, .Net Core never really went out of beta in VS2015...

Comment: Hm I looked up VS freezing when it first came out and it looked like other people had the same problem. But at my home it's a different computer, today is a different day, ... I have no other choice- I will give it a new solid go round! Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so I installed VS2017, but things didn't quite work either as far as updating all available update packages to 2.0.0, so then I saw that I need VS2017 15.3 Preview(2).. I installed that, and still although I made a new template project targeting the .NET Core App 2.0, it puts in all packages of version 1.1.2 and provides 14 available updates, which never work with the result "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes...". I do not understand, what is still missing?

Comment: I meanwhile started using the .Net Core (Framework) template, and that appears to be working fine. Once I figure out my Core Core error, I'll already have some useful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer came in form of comment:

VS2015 is no longer supported for .Net Core projects. You need to upgrade and migrate your project.json to .csproj too. – DavidG